# json_array_elements returns empty dataset in postgres

Tags: postgresql, query, json, jsonb, json-path

I was trying to read elements from Json array inside another array that is stored on Postgres database, but my result set was always empty.
My table looks like below:
[image]

Sample Json from table:

```
{"test":{"accountName":"OS1U","details":[{"status":{"statusCode":"Test Ready","modifiedDate":"2023-07-31T14:53:49Z"},"products":[{"productId":"0001","productName":"2GB","productDescription":"testproduct12"},{"productId":"0005","productName":"2GB","productDescription":"testproduct12"}]}]}}
```

Here my requirement is to get all the id's from table which is having productId (0001,0005). I tried below sql:

```
SELECT x.id 
FROM  (
    SELECT json_array_elements("json" -> 'test' -> 'details'->'products') AS products,"id"
    FROM   table_test b
       
   ) x
WHERE  x.products ->> 'productId' in ('0001','0005');
```

But it always returns empty dataset. Can anyone please guide me to correct the above statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that both `details` and `products` are arrays.

If you store it as `jsonb` then you can use `jsonb_path_exists` much more efficiently

```
SELECT t.id
FROM table_test t
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(t.json, '
  $.test.details[*].products[*].productId ? (@ == "0001" || @ == "0005")
  ');
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/6uy4rUWF)

Otherwise you need to do a series of `json_array_element` calls to unwrap each array.

```
SELECT t.id
FROM table_test t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
  FROM json_array_elements(t.json -> 'test' -> 'details') j1
  CROSS JOIN json_array_elements(j1 -> 'products') j2
  WHERE j2 ->> 'productId' IN ('0001', '0005')
);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/5hp7YjZE)

Comment: Thanks , It works now